# Modifying the InfoPath Form Validation Message

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I am building a customer facing SharePoint 2010 site that uses InfoPath 2010 for forms. My client does not like the default alert message that is displayed when the end user tries to submit a form containing validation errors: "InfoPath cannot submit the form because it contains errors. Errors are marked with either a red asterisk (required fields) or a red, dashed border (invalid values)." Understandably, my client's issue with this message is that it does not look professional on a customer facing site. We would like to change the first sentence to: "The form cannot be submitted because it contains errors.”

[One solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/3dc56deb-5643-4192-9996-4ca84095da87) to this problem involves changing the system file intlcorestrings.js, which appears to contain all of the string constants for InfoPath Forms Services. This file is located in the following directory: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\INC
Understandably, the system administrator is not crazy about this idea because it involves changes to system files that would impact all InfoPath forms on the server. It would also be one more thing we would have to keep track of when doing an upgrade. However, to me, this change does not seem to be that risky.

So my question is: Is there a better way to modify the InfoPath validation message? If not, does modifying the intlcorestrings.js file seem like a reasonable, low risk solution to this problem? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a heads up, modifying files in the SharePoint Root (the 14 folder) will probably be reverted back when a cumulative update or service pack is installed, and is generally considered a bad idea.

Alternatives? Not too sure to be honest... just make sure you back up that directory ;)

Comment: In case the update changes the intlcorestrings.js file, do you think it would it be better to just re-apply the modification after the udpate?  It's just a one liner.

Comment: marking this as the answer because there doesn't appear to be any alternative to changing the system file